# How to sum a product between 2 columns only if one other column contains a specific content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets, in the sheet1 i have a column with the names, a column with the price and a column with the worked time, i want to put a formula in the sheet2 who will sum the price multiplied by the worked time only if the name is the same then the name in a cell in sheet2 ...

SUMIF with a product inside and the condition is a Boolean formula who will test the name in sheet2 and the name in sheet1 and say if they are the same. I failed because we cannot put a product in a sum.

Comment: Hi Samy! This looks like Excel. I was wondering why it is tagged with python

Comment: can you not use a pivot table?

Comment: I don't know whats a pivot table on excel and how to use it

Comment: Yes, my bad, I changed the description

Comment: Have you tried looking into `SUMPRODUCT()` function? And will it be possible for you to post some copiable mock up data

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statement with SUMPRODUCT to get your answer.

=SUMPRODUCT(IF(*Name Range*=*Name*,1,0),*Price Range*,*Worked Time Range*)

The below link is a good reference.

https://exceljet.net/formulas/sumproduct-with-if

Comment: You can remove the need for `IF` with `--(NameRange = Name)`

Comment: That does look better, but I'm not sure on the poster's experience and thought that the IF statement might be easier to read.  The Boolean logic method is covered in the link I referenced to.